# How to detect EOF on android bluetooth file transfer?

Tags: android, file, bluetooth

I have implemented a bluetooth connection using the now-classic Google Bluetooth Chat code.  However, I have a question which I just cannot seem to wrap my brain around.

The reading of the input stream goes something like this:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, that's fine if I was just printing out the characters I was receiving as in the original example.  However, suppose I wanted to transfer an image file.  I don't know the size of the file, so I cannot count the bytes received or anything like that.  In my tests, I don't seem to be ever receiving a "-1" from the input stream, which appears to be the "norm" for reading from input streams.  So how can I know that I have reached the end of the file that was being sent?

Thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Android bluetooth input streams never return -1.

I guess setup a simple protocol by sending file size in the first place and EOF signals at last will help.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case, but I wanted to see if there was a simpler way I was overlooking.  But you've confirmed what I have to do...  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. Android sends -1 only when the Socket is closed as far as I know. So a workaround could be to do a reconnect, but I was trying that for hours and did not get it working, since I do not understand this "special" Code here (copied from a Stackoverflow Thread) for setting up the socket:

```
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    Log.d(TAG, "New Connection initialized");
    Method m;
    try {
        m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                new Class[] { int.class });
        tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mmSocket = tmp;
```

This Socket only works, when my App is started for the first filetransfer. If I want to "Reconnect" with a completely new instantiated Object (and a new Socket created with that Code), the program freezes on the blocking method mmSocket.connect(). It seems like the Method never comes to an ending. This is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while ((bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer) != -1)
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;
        ArrayList<Integer> arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (true) {
            try {
                int data = mmInStream.read();
                if(mmInStream.available()>0) {
                    arr_byte.add(data);
                } else {
                    arr_byte.add(data);
                    buffer = new byte[arr_byte.size()];
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_byte.size() ; i++) {
                        buffer[i] = arr_byte.get(i).byteValue();
                    }
                    Log.e("INPUT",new String(buffer));
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                    arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```